# Is there a way to change variable values while debugging JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I have a breakpoint on this piece of code (using Firebug):

```
if (validator.formValidate([dom.forumid]))
```

How can I skip this validation part and get into the `if` clause even if my `dom.forumid` is not valid, i.e. the call to `formValidate()` returns `false`? So how can I make it return `true`?

I was thinking about modifying the JavaScript, but I don't know how that's done.

Comment: Firebug doesn't change code, it reads it, and validates it.  You can use // to turn off javaScript validating.

Comment: @Placeholders_in_use I dont run the server so I cant change the source code files

Comment: Do you run the client?

Comment: @Placeholders_in_use yeah, I am visiting my friend's website, so my question is how I can get past the clientside validation. I want to see if he's done any server validation.

Comment: That's a whole different question, because you're wanting to send data to the page, not change the code.

Comment: @Placeholders_in_use Yeah, I was thinking this might've been a way to get it done. Can you consult me in the right direction?

Comment: Ask the question of "With firebug, or other software is there a way to send other variable values through JavaScript?".

Comment: not completely, you also need to rephrase the body.  I tried changing questions this way, and got on question ban :'(

Comment: @Placeholders_in_use lol fixed, good luck with lifting it. Would you know the answer to my question?

Comment: I just need a few up votes, and no, I don't :(, I'm more of a PHP guy.

Comment: If it's the website of your friend, why don't you tell him he should check his server-side validation? Also note that you could simply turn off JavaScript to disable the client-side validation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Firebug I do this by entering an assignment into the watch input field

- to assign a new value
- to assign a new function that returns the value I expect

This also works in Chrome ~33 (just tested) execpt: one has to enter the assignment into the console (which actually works in Firefox too, but using the watch panel is faster :).

In Firebug, you have to edit and re-save the assignment typed into the input on each break.

Of course, replacing the function will prevent the code from functioning normally on further runs. To avoid this one might save the original value to `window._savedFnX` or so and then do the assingment again assigning the saved function/value. But I think this is a workaround from saving one stepping through the code again and again to reach the point of interest. I often realize that there's a bad condition and then I want to continue (while the code would not) to test the rest of the code.

Take a look at these screenshots:

### Code background

In the screenshot `photo` is an instance with this code:

```
{
   ...
   _loaded: false, // set to true on some condition
   ...
   isLoaded: function(){
       return this._loaded;
   },
   ...
}
```

The method `isLoaded()` will be replaced in the example to always return true. :)

### Firebug

(Applies to Firebug ~1.12)

- Stop at breakpoint
- Go to the console
- Assign function that returns the value you want to the variable **in scope** (or being reachable) `[ORANGE]`

The `[BLUE]` box highlights the the value that would be returned by `isLoaded()` and the value that is being returned by the replaced function.

[image: Screenshot of Firebug showing the watch panel with replaced function]

### Chrome

(Applies to Chrome ~34.0)

*Note:* in Chrome you can also edit the source code and re-run the modified version.

- Stop at breakpoint
- Go to the console
- Assign function that returns the value you want to the variable **in scope** (or being reachable) `[ORANGE]`
- (Refresh to see the result) `[GREEN]`

The `[BLUE]` box highlights the the value that would be returned by `isLoaded()` and the value that is being returned by the replaced function.

[image: Screenshot of Chome console showing the console with replaced function and the watch panel with new return value]

Comment: so basically you just redeclare the function when ur at the breakpoint?

Comment: using the console worked for me

Answer (score 37):

As of today (Chrome 67) you can just double-click any variable on the right hand side under the "Scope" section and edit it in real-time.

[image]

Comment: Could you add another { key: value } inside the variable "win"? Instead of modifying name, or patient.

Comment: this doesn't seem to actually edit the variable to me, after i hit enter, it goes back to the value it had before

Comment: Then you probably have a script that is resetting the value; rest-assured, editing variables here are specifically for this, so your script is just changing it back is all. Try pausing execution or stepping through execution, or set a breakpoint on whatever is chaning it.